# Store arbitrary object in a PropertyBusinessObject

Tags: codenameone

This question is specific for Codename One.

Is it possible to store any arbitrary object in a PropertyBusinessObject? In the examples in the developers guide and in the Codename One blog I found only Strings, Numerics and Dates. What do I have to do to store inside a User PropertyBusinessObject a new class created by me?

For example, suppose that I need to associate a User with a Sport object (that is a POJO with several attributes) and the Sport object contains a Team object (that is another POJO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the builtin support is for `PropertyBusinessObject` to reference other `PropertyBusinessObject` instances so `Team` or `Sport` shouldn't be POJO's but rather `PropertyBusinessObject` instances.

Having said that it's still useful to be able to work with other objects. E.g. I might want to store the `Location` object or an `Image` (we do use `EncodedImage` in some cases). The theoretical syntax is identical:

```
public final Property<MyObject, ParentClass> prop = new Property<>(MyObject.class);
```

The problem with this is the word "store".

We need an API that will map such objects to JSON/Map/Database etc. and that API just wasn't defined yet. It should be a relatively simple interface we just didn't define it yet. There are a few RFE's in the queue for 5.0 related to properties, I'm not sure if one of them covers this.